# Get Instagram data from a backend

Tags: instagram-api

It is possible to get data from Instagram users, like number of posts, profile photo etc from a backend service? I don't want to force my user to login into his Instagram account to get those informations.
I'm reading about Instagram new api but always it talks about oauth which implied force login vis frontend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why would Instagram give some users data, without login? Only possible option is through Instagram public APIs, using OAuth/OIDC.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use someone else's token (... yours?) to fetch informations about users and posts.

But that will always be limited.... for example users with non public profile, you won't be able to see those, or maybe you'll loose some posts, ....